# Why is Samba on Ubuntu Server not asking for a password?

Tags: server, samba

I have looked at other answers on the web and on this site, but most of them seem to be for people who want to use Samba without a password.  We have a mostly Windows 7 network.  We set up Samba on our Ubuntu Server machine.  Here are the relevant parts of the config file:

```
workgroup = our.windows.domain
security = user
[sharename]
comment = my share
path = /home/myuser
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0755
```

After making these changes to the config file and trying to connect the first time, I got in without a password.  Anyone on our local network can mount the share \1.2.3.4\sharename without being asked for a password.  I want it to ask me for the Linux username and password.  What step have I missed?  Is there any other info you need to help me?

Thanks in advance!

Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Windows will supply the local user's credentials when connecting to a network share. You have configured a Windows domain, so presumably users would use the same credentials to log on to their workstations and to connect to the Samba share. Thus the above behavior on a Windows client is normal.

Comment: I think you're right, so I followed up with a test.  I tried the `valid users` setting and added myself.  I could get in without a password.  I removed myself from that and added a different user (not my logged-in Windows user) and I was asked for a password.  My credentials didn't work, but the other user's credentials did.  So, I'm just waiting for someone else in the office here to try to connect to my share.  I think since I have listed myself as the only valid user, no one else will be able to get in.  I'll post the results here as soon as possible!